# Is Multi-Attach of Volume (EBS) allowed only for Nitro-based instances on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I want to share one volume between 2 instances on AWS. 1st instance is **t2.large** and 2nd instance is **g2.2xlarge**.
After I tried to modify the existing volume type to iops2 and allow *Multi-Attach* option, it showed up, that Multi-attach is not allowed for this instance type (t2.large).

What instance types are allowed for this option? As a 2nd instance, I need instance with GPU. Aren't these instance types (g-types) allowed for this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`t2.large` nor `g2.2xlarge` are not nitro. The list of nitro instances is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances) and includes:

> Virtualized: A1, C5, C5a, C5ad, C5d, C5n, C6g, C6gd, C6gn, D3, D3en, G4, I3en, Inf1, M5, M5a, M5ad, M5d, M5dn, M5n, M5zn, M6g, M6gd, p3dn.24xlarge, P4, R5, R5a, R5ad, R5b, R5d, R5dn, R5n, R6g, R6gd, T3, T3a, T4g, and z1d

> Bare metal: a1.metal, c5.metal, c5d.metal, c5n.metal, c6g.metal, c6gd.metal, i3.metal, i3en.metal, m5.metal, m5d.metal, m5dn.metal, m5n.metal, m5zn.metal, m6g.metal, m6gd.metal, mac1.metal, r5.metal, r5b.metal, r5d.metal, r5dn.metal, r5n.metal, r6g.metal, r6gd.metal, u-6tb1.metal, u-9tb1.metal, u-12tb1.metal, u-18tb1.metal, u-24tb1.metal, and z1d.metal

**Update**

ALternatively, you can use [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) which works with not only **all instance types**, but also ECS containers and lambda functions.

Comment: Does that mean, I cannot use Multi-Attach option on EC2 with GPU ?

Comment: @MichaelKnave G4 are nitro instances with gpu. But do you really need multi-attache? Why not use EFS instead?

Comment: Well, it looks, that it's my solition. I have created one EFS, and then simply mounted it to the both ec2 machines. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These are some fundamental differences between **EBS v/s EFS**
`which might help someone when to use either of them`.

- sharing of one volume with multiple instance in the same az is allow with provisioned iops ebs type volumes however those instance should be nitro instances.[AWS says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html#considerations) *"Multi-Attach enabled volumes can be attached to up to 16 Linux instances built on the Nitro System that are in the same Availability Zone."*
- The use case for multi attach is very specific, it is ideal for **clustered linux applications that  needs great availability, concurrent write operations, also you have to use file system which is clustered wared ( can't use xfs, ex4 etc)**.
- EFS allows `100,1000's of concurrent ec2 instance in multi AZ ( single az is also poissble) but only for Linux instance`.
- Use case for EFs is content sharing, content management, Wordpress.
- EBS is provisioned approach while EFS is pay per use so for a less data you will pay less, however EFS cost more than EBS.
- EBS also support lifycle management tier to move file to IA- infrequent tier to reduce cost.

[docs for efs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/how-it-works.html)

Comment: "life cycle management" - you probably meant that EFS supports that, and not EBS? (the keys are like right next to each other). EBS life cycle management is about creating and deleting snapshots and not about reduced storage cost.

Comment: A few other things to note about EFS compared to EBS:
**(1)** With storage life cycle management, depending on your usage, EFS can be much cheaper than EBS, not only because you don't have to pre-allocate all the storage you are going to need, but also because byte-per-byte, with a high percentage of IA storage, it will be massively cheaper. **(2)** EFS without provisioned IO is bog slow and you'll be sorry if you try to serve websites (such as Wordpress) off of it, and with provisioned IO it is indeed much more expensive than EBS. I learned that lesson the hard way.